# Angular factory not returning object property

Tags: angularjs, object, properties

I can return an object, but not the object property. Why? I have tried many things but nothing seems to work.  Sorry but I'm new in Angular

```
app.factory('myData', function() {

  var data = {
    product: ''
  };


  function addItem(value) {
    data.product = value;
  }

  function getList() {
    return data.product;
  }

  return {
    addItem: addItem,
    getList: getList
  };

});
```

Updated with the controllers functions

```
function controllerA(myData){

  var scope = this;
  scope.total = 0;

  scope.addMore = function(){
    scope.total++;
    myData.addItem(scope.total);
  }

}

function controllerB(myData){

  var scope = this;
  scope.total = 0;
  scope.total = myData.getList();

}
```

Comment: This looks alright. when you call `getList()` you get `undefined` or `''`?

Comment: Could you make a plunkr of this? As muli stated this looks like it should return the object property alright

Comment: So, what is the code that "doesn't work", what do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: It may have something to do with the type of the content you pas to the function, try a console.log(typeof value)

Comment: I've updated my post with more details about the controllers.

Comment: getList is always " ", but when I return the full object it works fine

Comment: How do you use you controllers? You need to be more specific about the encountered error. What is your exact test case?

Answer (score 1):

The total in controller B is initialized when the controller is instantiated.

The total in controller A is modified when `addMore()` is called. So if you call `addMore()` *after* controller B is instantiated, controller B will always reference the original value ot the total: the empty string:

```
 t0: controller A is instantiated
 t1: controller B is instantiated. B.total is initialized with the result of myData.getList(), which is the empty string:

   data.product -------\
                       |
                       V
   B.total -------> empty string


 t2: a.addMore() is called. That modifies the service's total, but not the variable in B

  data.product ---> 1


   B.total -------> empty string
```

If you reference the object itself in the controller, you don't have this problem, because B has a reference to data, and data.product is modified by A.

Comment: Thank you. I think that is the problem. But what could I do then?

Comment: @cdz Return the object from your service. Returning primitives from services almost always results in this type of situation where the value in your controller will never update.

Answer (score 0):

You can read good article:

[aticle](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2527-defining-instantiatable-classes-in-the-angularjs-dependency-injection-framework.htm)

```
  demo.factory(
            "Friend",
            function( trim ) {
                // Define the constructor function.
                function Friend( firstName, lastName ) {
                    this.firstName = trim( firstName || "" );
                    this.lastName = trim( lastName || "" );
                }
                // Define the "instance" methods using the prototype
                // and standard prototypal inheritance.
                Friend.prototype = {
                    getFirstName: function() {
                        return( this.firstName );
                    },
                    getFullName: function() {
                        return( this.firstName + " " + this.lastName );
                    }
                };
                // Define the "class" / "static" methods. These are
                // utility methods on the class itself; they do not
                // have access to the "this" reference.
                Friend.fromFullName = function( fullName ) {
                    var parts = trim( fullName || "" ).split( /\s+/gi );
                    return(
                        new Friend(
                            parts[ 0 ],
                            parts.splice( 0, 1 ) && parts.join( " " )
                        )
                    );
                };
                // Return constructor - this is what defines the actual
                // injectable in the DI framework.
                return( Friend );
            }
        );
```